# Why did they pick the title 'Tangled'?

Tags: production, title, tangled

I heard that Disney wanted to have a [gender neutral movie name](http://articles.latimes.com/2010/mar/09/business/la-fi-ct-disney9-2010mar09) for Rapunzel story to target boys too but why did they end up with *Tangled*? Did they ever address how they ended up choosing this name?

Comment: Congratulations, this question is the winner of the [corresponding topic challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4384/49).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**In reference to the tangled connections between the characters.**

Disney was originally going to call the movie *Rapunzel Unbraided*<sup>[[1]](https://www.boredpanda.com/rapunzel-unbraided-tangled/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=organic)</sup>. However, after the failure of *The Princess and the Frog*<sup>[[2]](http://articles.latimes.com/2010/mar/09/business/la-fi-ct-disney9-2010mar09)</sup>, Disney decided to take a hint from Pixar and make their titles more gender neutral:

> Disney hopes the introduction of the slightly bad-boy character will help it tab the broadest possible audience for "Tangled", emulating the success of its corporate sibling, Pixar. Pixar's movies have been huge hits because they appear to girls, boys, and adults. Its most recent release, "Up", grossed more than $700 million worldwide.
>
> "The Princess and the Frog" generated considerably less — $222 million in global ticket sales to date.
>
> "Based upon the response from fans and critics, we believe it would have been higher if it wasn't prejudged by its title," Catmull said.
>   <sub>([LAtimes](http://articles.latimes.com/2010/mar/09/business/la-fi-ct-disney9-2010mar09))</sub>

Finally, they decided on "Tangled":

> In rethinking "Rapunzel", Disney tested a number of titles, finally settling on "Tangled" because people responded to meanings beyond the obvious hair reference: a twisted version of the familiar story and the tangled relationship between the two lead characters.
>   <sub>(ibid)</sub>

Comment: In Japan, the movie is called Rapunzel on Top of the Tower　（塔の上のラプンツェル）. Any idea why Disney did not adopt the same tactic there?

Comment: @SupremeGrandRuler Seems like a good new question, not good for a comment addition.

Comment: I forget my source (probably Ed Catmull's Creativity Inc.) but I believe there was internal friction between the marketing department and Catmull/Lasseter for Princess and the Frog. Marketing saying "you can't say princess in the title" while the creatives held their ground. After the poor results of Princess and the Frog, the creatives paid more heed to marketing and changed the name for Tangled.

Comment: @SupremeGrandRuler: The title is Rapunzel also in French, German and Italian (In some versions - e.g. Italian - it also has a subtitle with a pun). Maybe the gender-neutral title wasn't mandatory everywhere? BTW, Frozen has "Frozen Kingdom" subtitle in Italian, but Ice/Snow Queen in French and German

Comment: Similarly, in Polish version, the title "Zaplątani" (no subtitle) uses form that specifically refers to tangled people (plural - men or mixed gender). That form would be incorrect for just the hair (that would call for "zaplątane"). We have history of terribly mistranslated titles in Poland (e.g. "Glass Trap" for "Die Hard") but this one is very fitting, with the hair reference present but secondary)

Answer (score 7):

Nathan Greno:

> The original intention was to make a film more closely related to
>   something like Cinderella, where your main character is Cinderella,
>   and there’s also a prince that’s in the movie that shows up once in a
>   while. So we started developing: Okay, who is the male character in
>   the show? We started playing around with scenes with our writer, Dan
>   Fogelman, and doing this banter thing back and forth [between Rapunzel
>   and Flynn]. And very early on, without realizing it, we were creating
>   this duo. That’s what eventually lead to the title change. Just as you
>   wouldn’t call Toy Story “Buzz Lightyear,” we really needed a title
>   that represented what the film is, and that it’s a duo, and it stars
>   Rapunzel and Flynn Ryder.

Ed Catmull, president of Pixar and Disney Animation Studios said:

> We did not want to be put in a box. Some people might assume it's a
>   fairy tale for girls when it's not. We make movies to be appreciated
>   and loved by everybody.

It seems Disney is trying hard to capture the interest of more boys, which also explains their recent acquisition of the Marvel Comic universe.

What Floyd Norman, a retired Disney and Pixar animator told the LA Times:

> The idea of changing the title of a classic like Rapunzel to Tangled
>   is beyond stupid,
>   I'm still hoping that Disney will eventually regain their sanity and
>   return the title of their movie to what it should be. I'm convinced
>   they'll gain nothing from this except the public seeing Disney as
>   desperately trying to find an audience.

<sup>[Google is always correct](https://ew.com/article/2010/11/24/tangled-rapunzel-nathan-greno-byron-howard/). [And this too](https://www.cinemablend.com/new/Real-Reason-Disney-Changed-Rapunzel-Tangled-17472.html).</sup>

Comment: Who's this Norman you quote?

Comment: @AakashM Seems to be a critic.

Comment: ["Floyd Norman, a retired Disney and Pixar animator, lampooned the new name with a cartoon on his blog..."](http://articles.latimes.com/2010/mar/09/business/la-fi-ct-disney9-2010mar09)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert link not available

Comment: @freedomn-m:  Hmm, works for me.  Here's [the same quote repeated in the Daily Telegraph](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/film/film-news/7407398/Rapunzel-renamed-by-Disney-because-it-doesnt-appeal-to-boys.html);  perhaps that will work.

Comment: Thanks for the updated link.  I should have been more specific - it's not "not working" - it's "unavailable", specifically (from the link) : *"Unfortunately, our website is currently unavailable in most European countries."*

Comment: From the article: _"Concluding it had too many animated girl flicks in its lineup, Disney has shelved its long-gestating project "The Snow Queen," based on the Hans Christian Andersen story."_ Well, thank goodness they were wrong... that movie ended up being the most successful animated film in history. _And it wasn't named after a princess._